# Toastr throws TypeError for toastr.info('msg')

Tags: javascript, toastr

I am trying out toastr but I keep getting a strange TypeError that does not make any sense to me.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
at getOptions (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/toastr/toastr.js:391:25)
```

I had my project scaffolded with yeoman gulp-angular and properly injected toastr into controller where I want to test it. 
Line I tried is simply:

```
toastr.info('A message.');
```

toastr is present in the page - inserted by a gulp task.
How to find out what went wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery library might not be included. 
toastr getOptions method is trying to extend the config that was passed in  when you initialized toastr.

Comment: Due to some strange error in my Gulp task config jquery was not included indeed... Pity that the error couldn't just say "JQuery not available".

Comment: Jquery was included in my project.....all I needed to do is to include the toastr after the jquery. The toastr needed to be below the jquery.